# Failed to connect my Firebase DB with PHP SDK

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using [ktamas77/firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) at github to connect my Firebase data.

My code below. Replaced of confidential info with ******.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My web</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
         require_once 'firebase/firebaseLib.php';
         require_once 'firebase/firebaseStub.php';
         require_once 'firebase/firebaseInterface.php';

         echo "1";

         const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://********.firebaseio.com/';
         const DEFAULT_TOKEN = '***************************************';
         const DEFAULT_PATH = '/firebase/example';

         echo "2";

         $firebase = new Firebase(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN); 

         echo "3";

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried:

`$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);`

Output is: `1 2`. It seems it fails while it is trying to create the new Firebase.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hey did you find any way if integration if yes please guide me for the same

Comment: Did you tried to set "error_reporting(E_ALL);" and "ini_set('display_errors', '1');" to see an error?

Comment: Also check that curl-extension is installed this will be tested in FirebaseLib-constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try it. but i am not sure because evrything look fine from here:

```
const DEFAULT_URL = 'h://abc.com/';
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'yourToken:XYZ';
const DEFAULT_PATH = '/firebase/example';

$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your library is loaded properly? Pls add directory/file structure.

You can test loaded library with

```
class_exists ('Firebase')
```

or

```
file_exists ( 'firebase/firebaseLib.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, enable your PHP error logging `error_log(E_ALL)` to get the error message retrieved
also, check your internet connection because everything looks fine

Answer (score 0):

For people who are still searching for an solution without using composer you could try the following:

```
<?php
require_once('./src/firebaseLib.php');
require_once('./src/firebaseStub.php');
require_once('./src/firebaseInterface.php');
  
$URL = 'xxx';
$TOKEN = 'xxx';

$firebase = new FirebaseLib($URL, $TOKEN);

// Reading the stored string
$name = $firebase->get('/',['orderBy' => '"ID"','equalTo' => '"1309"']);

var_dump($name);

?>
```